# Why is "genius" often misspelt as "geniOus"? What are its etymons, etymology, homonyms and similar words?

Tags: homophones, homonyms, homographs

Why do people confuse between similar or related words: genius, ingenious, genuous and ingenuous? 
Why has "genious" not been a valid word unlike both genuous and ingenuous, and genuine and ingenuine?
What are etymons, etymology, homonyms and related words for the genius, ingenious, genuous, ingenuous, genuine and ingenuine?

Answer (score 4):

The suffix ***[-ous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ous&allowed_in_frame=0)*** is a fairly common one, so it may just be a mistake  made by people unfamiliar with the correct  spelling of the term.   The term ***ingenious*** may also be responsible for the mistake.  ***Genius*** is the correct spelling that  comes directly from Latin:

> - word-forming element making adjectives from nouns, meaning "having, full of, having to do with, doing, inclined to," from Old French -ous, -eux, from Latin -osus.

[Genius](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=genius&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.):

> - late 14c., "tutelary or moral spirit" who guides and governs an individual through life, ***from Latin genius*** "guardian deity or spirit which watches over each person from birth; spirit, incarnation; wit, talent;" also "prophetic skill," originally "generative power".

[Ingenious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ingenious):

> - early 15c., "intellectual, talented," ***from Middle French ingénieux "clever, ingenious" (Old French engeignos), from Latin ingeniosus "of good natural capacity, full of intellect, clever, gifted with ginius***.

(Etymonline)

Answer (score -3):

Primary cause is ignorance.  That's where spellcheck is useful.  In some cases words are spelled differently in British English and American English.